# Using Android build.xml in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build.xml

I have an android project which has an Ant buildfile. It works great via the command-line:

```
rascher@coltrane:~/git/$ ant
Buildfile: build.xml
    [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 8
    [setup] Project Target: Android 2.1-update1
    [setup] API level: 7
    [setup] 

    ... etc etc etc ...
```

But when I try to use this in eclipse, `build.xml` has a red-X.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyWonderfulProject" default="help">
```

`<project` is underlined with the error: **Default target help does not exist in this project**

It seems like everybody else on the internet has this issue, and it seems to be caused by the fact that `build.xml` is using directives that come from the multiple nested android-specific files that this buildfile imports.

I have other projects in my workspace that use Eclipse's build mechanism, so I know that my environment is able to compile, run, and deploy Android applications without an issue. But this buildfile is giving me headaches.

What is the fix?

Answer (score 13):

Option 1:

Import the Android ant template file in the build.xml file. Assuming you have `sdk.dir` defined in `local.properties` and pointing to your Android installation directory, add the following under the project element:

```
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/platforms/${target}/templates/android_rules.xml" />
```

Option 2:

To actually use the Android ant targets in the Eclipse ant perspective, the above will not help. There seems to be some general level incompatibility that I haven't figured out to resolve completely, but to get things working at a satisfactory level though you can:

- Import the project build.xml as a a builder. Project properties -> Builders -> import.
- **Do not use option 1**. Instead ignore the warning about the missing template. Global properties -> Ant -> Editor -> Problems. Add build.xml to names.

This will have an impact on all projects and ignore actual errors, so it's not a perfect solution. But you can use the Android build options inside Eclipse, as well as from the command line.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction! Follow-up: now the red-X's go away when I view build.xml. But in the Ant perspective it still has an error: `Cannot find ${sdk.dir}/platforms/${target}/templates/android_rules.xml imported from ...`. When I hover over the variables in the editor, the correct values pop up. But the Ant perspective doesn't seem to do that substitution. Help?

Comment: You made my day, Tatu Lahtela!!  Thanks for the great answer, that helped so much!! :-)

Comment: This almost works! The Ant perspective does not show the targets in my build.xml so that I can double click on an individual target. Do you get the same behavior?

Comment: They appear if you add the row in option 1 and then remove it. Strange behavior indeed.

Comment: In my distribution, the android_rules.xml file only exists in android-3, 4, 7, and 8.

Comment: I have Option 1 working in Eclipse for me, but this needs to still work on the command-line for others in my team who aren't using Eclipse. I put the <import file="${sdk.dir}... line just BELOW the  <loadproperties srcFile="local.properties" /> line and the {sdk.dir} was substituted from the command-line, as you'd expect. But the {target} is still not substituted, though. Rather than try to fix that I just added an optional="true" attribute to the <import>, which now has things working in Eclipse AND on the command-line.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't fix the problem, but it will make Eclipse stop getting in your way. Go to `Window > Preferences > Ant > Editor`, and select the `Problems` tab. Check the `ignore all buildfile problems` box.

Comment: This almost works! The Ant perspective does not show the targets in my build.xml so that I can double click on an individual target. Do you get the same behavior?

Comment: After checking the ignore box had to open/close build.xml to make the error disappear.

Answer (score 6):

There is one target called 'help' defined in the ${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/main_rules.xml like below,

```
<target name="help">

    <echo>Android Ant Build. Available targets:</echo>
    <echo>   help:      Displays this help.</echo>
    <echo>   clean:     Removes output files created by other targets.</echo>
    <echo>   compile:   Compiles project's .java files into .class files.</echo>
    <echo>   debug:     Builds the application and signs it with a debug key.</echo>
    <echo>   release:   Builds the application. The generated apk file must be</echo>
    <echo>              signed before it is published.</echo>
    <echo>   install:   Installs/reinstalls the debug package onto a running</echo>
    <echo>              emulator or device.</echo>
    <echo>              If the application was previously installed, the</echo>
    <echo>              signatures must match.</echo>
    <echo>   uninstall: Uninstalls the application from a running emulator or</echo>
    <echo>              device.</echo>
</target>
```

copy this one to your build.xml and it should works.

Comment: Seems to work. Actually, all you need is <target name="help" />

Answer (score 2):

I has same issue and all i did was goto on the eclipse

```
Window->Preferences->Ant->Editor->Problems
```

and click

```
Ignore All Build File Problems.
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer, but for what it's worth, I was able to make the problem go away by removing the eclipse project from the workspace, deleting .* in my project directory and starting over.  Eclipse FTW!

Answer (score 0):

If your build.xml has its own help target rather than relying on the imported one, then you need to put that target before the line

```
<taskdef name="setup" classname="com.android.ant.SetupTask" classpathref="android.antlibs" />
```

Comment: I have a similar issue, and have no self-defined help target.  the help target from android_rules.xml should be used, but even pasting it into the build.xml file doesn't resolve this error. (eclipse 3.6, android skd 10, target is android-7) building with ant on command line works perfectly.